# Scraping URL directory IDs in R

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, rvest

What's the best way to scrape all contents of a URL directory that doesn't have an id number sequence in R? I'd like to get all contents inside `http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/album/` but the URL format is `http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/album/[BAND NAME]/[ALBUM NAME]`for all contents in that directory.
I tried to account for all characters inside he albums directory but

```
bandurls <- unlist(lapply(LETTERS, function(letter)  
xpathSApply(htmlParse(paste0("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/ListArtistsAlpha.aspx?letter=", letter)), '//div[@class="artistsListContainer"]/ul/li/a', xmlGetAttr, "href") 
))
bands <- setNames(sub(".*/(.*)", "\\1", bandurls), bandurls)

albums <- sapply(bands, function(band) {
doc <- htmlParse(paste0("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/artist/", band))
sapply(doc[paste0('//div[@class="discographyContainer"]/a[starts-with(@href,"/album/', band, '")]')], xmlGetAttr, "href")
})


URL <- sprintf("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com", albums)

METAL.SCRAPER <- function(ID) {
  PaGE <- try(html(sprintf(URL, ID)), silent=TRUE)
  if (inherits(PaGE, "try-error")) {
    data.frame(Band=character(0), Year=character(0), Tracklist=character(0),Lineup=character(0),
           Release=character(0), Genre=character(0), Rating=character(0))
  } else {
    data.frame(Band=PaGE %>% html_nodes(xpath='//head') %>% html_text(),
           Year=PaGE %>% html_nodes(xpath='//h3[1]') %>% html_text(),
           Tracklist=PaGE %>% html_nodes(xpath='//div[@id="albumInfosDetails"]') %>% html_text(),
           Lineup=PaGE %>% html_nodes(xpath='//div[@id="albumInfosDetails"]') %>% html_text(),
           Release=PaGE %>% html_nodes(xpath='//div[@id="albumInfosDetails"]') %>% html_text(),
           Genre=PaGE %>% html_nodes(xpath='//span[@id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_AlbumInfosRepeater_ctl00_FiledUnderLabel"]') %>% html_text(),
           Rating=PaGE %>% html_nodes(xpath='//span[@itemprop="average"]') %>% html_text(),
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 }
}

Sys.sleep(2)

DaTa <- rbindlist(pblapply(URL, METAL.SCRAPER))

Warning messages:
1: In if (grepl("^http", x)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (grepl("^http", x)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (grepl("^http", x)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, here's one way to scrape it:

```
library(XML)
bandurls <- unlist(lapply(LETTERS, function(letter)  
  xpathSApply(htmlParse(paste0("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/ListArtistsAlpha.aspx?letter=", letter)), '//div[@class="artistsListContainer"]/ul/li/a', xmlGetAttr, "href") 
))
bands <- setNames(sub(".*/(.*)", "\\1", bandurls), bandurls)
albums <- sapply(bands, function(band) {
  doc <- htmlParse(paste0("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/artist/", band))
  sapply(doc[paste0('//div[@class="discographyContainer"]/a[starts-with(@href, "/album/', band, '")]')], xmlGetAttr, "href")
})
albums
# $`/artist/a-band-called-pain`
# [1] "/album/a-band-called-pain/broken-dreams" "/album/a-band-called-pain/broken-dreams"
# 
# $`/artist/a-band-of-orcs`
# [1] "/album/a-band-of-orcs/warchiefs-of-the-apocalypse(ep)"
# [2] "/album/a-band-of-orcs/warchiefs-of-the-apocalypse(ep)"
# [3] "/album/a-band-of-orcs/hall-of-the-frozen-dead(single)"
# [4] "/album/a-band-of-orcs/hall-of-the-frozen-dead(single)"
# ...
```

However, before scraping the site you should 
**ask the webmaster if you are allowed to do so.** \m/

Comment: Thanks @lukeA. I updated my question to reflect what I am looking for more accurately. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for `sprintf("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/album/%s/%s", bandnames, albumnames)`?

Comment: Yes--can the objects `bands` and `albums` in your above code be used in `sprintf("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/album/%s/%s", bands, albums)`?

Comment: No, my example already has all album urls in the `albums` list: _"/album/a-band-called-pain/broken-dreams"_ = _"/album/BANDNAME/ALBUMNAME"_.

Comment: I get a warning message when I create the URL object and run the scraper in my above code: `URL <- sprintf("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com", albums)`  Warning messages:
`1: In if (grepl("^http", x)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: You can use `URL <- paste0("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com", unlist(albums))` and adapt your function so that it takes a url as parameter. Then `DaTa <- do.call(rbind, lapply(URL, METAL.SCRAPER))`.